# why i have the error "borrowed value here after move" using an option inside a for?

Tags: rust

I am trying to take and replace the values of the option variables inside a for, I do not understand why I have this error if the match that is responsible for replacing the value of the option variables is in the same iteration

```
        let mut key = None;
        let mut value = None;

        for element in parser {
            match element.unwrap() {
                xml::reader::XmlEvent::StartElement { name, .. } => {
                    key.replace(name.local_name); //borrow of moved value: `key`  value borrowed here after move
                }
                xml::reader::XmlEvent::Characters(string) => {
                    value.replace(string); //borrow of moved value: `value`  value borrowed here after move
                }
                _ => {}
            }

            match (key, value) {
                (None, None) => todo!(),
                (None, Some(_)) => todo!(),
                (Some(_), None) => todo!(),
                (Some(_), Some(_)) => {
                    key.take();
                    value.take();
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Pretty sure it's because of `match (key, value)` at the end. Try `match (&key, &value)` instead.

Comment: @PitaJ thanks it works now! but this behavior seems a bit strange to me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To understand why @PitaJ's solution is correct, we have to realize the semantics of the `match` statement. Match statement will consume (move) an expression you give it. By giving the reference to a value, we force `match` to only inspect the value and do not move it.

Comment: Nitpick: *"Rust is not yet smart enough to prove you did not move the values"* -- Rust doesn't decide if a value is moved, _you_ decide based on whether you give something my value or by reference. Using `match` in this way is moving it, because that's what happens when you give something by value, not because Rust "can't figure it out."

Comment: @cdhowie, thank you, I sometimes get carried by imagination and make disruptive statements based on experience. Simply assumptions. Nevertheless, I deleted the section that does not even contribute to the answer.

Comment: Indeed, it's easy to personify our tools and ascribe them motives. :)